# django - Use foreign key for multi-table inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I am stuck in an odd position in my database design, and I would appreciate some comments. We are using django-shop for an e-commerce platform. There is a base class defined for products:

```
from polymorphic.polymorphic_model import PolymorphicModel

class BaseProduct(PolymorphicModel):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

We extended this base class for our own `Product` object:

```
class Product(BaseProduct):
    # custom fields
```

We now want to create another object, representing an offer to this `Product` object, something like:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    # more
```

We want this  `Offer` object to be added to the cart, and used in orders, just like the regular `Product` class. Yet, `Cart` and `Order` classes expects objects of type `Product`

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

So as it is, we can't add `Offer` objects to the cart, or save them in orders.

I was thinking of making `Offer` a subclass of `Product` as well, but instead of having a OneToOne relationship used in typical multi-table inheritance, somehow change it to a regular ForeignKey. I'm not even sure if this makes sense, let alone be possible.

Our database is already deployed in production with many `Product` objects, and this offer class is something we want to add on top, without modifying the rest.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: This might depend on how the behavior of `Offer` differs from `Product` in the cart.  Are they similar enough that an `Offer` can be considered a different type of `Product` and somehow work that into the current `Product` model?  Maybe there's something else with inheritance that can be done to keep you from having to change Product, that others might know about.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

```
class Offer(Product):

    products = ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='offers')
```

This will create an offer (which is also a product, and hence can be added to a cart) which also points at a number of related products.

Instead of "Adding an offer to the cart", why not use [django-shop-discounts](https://github.com/bmihelac/django-shop-discounts)?

Comment: The issue we found with this method was to decouple Offers and Products. I understand that in this method, if one creates an Offer object, this would also create a Product model and link the two. However, given that there already are Product objects in the DB, can we create one or multiple Offer objects, and overload their ``product_ptr`` to point to these existing objects?

Comment: I lied a bit, it's not a foreign key, but a one-to-one relation. so no, you can't have more than one Offer pointing at a single Product. See my edits.